# C# Chat - TCP P2P

Tags: c#, tcp, chat, p2p

I am working on a Peer-to-Peer chat program but have ran across an issue: Running the client and server simultaneously. I do not want a dedicated server to manage connections. I believe the solution may be asynchronous direct connections, but I am not sure.

What I am trying to accomplish is to be able to run the program between two hosts, the program will be started and begin trying to connect to an ip address specified by a text box. At the same time, it will also start listening for incoming connections on the localhost ip address.

***I am using tcp, because on the off chance something is corrupted the message will not be able to be read (it is encrypted)

Issues:
1) It is conceivable a client could be waiting for a period of time before the other program tries to connect. So should some form of a loop must be utilized? If so, how?

2) I assume I need to use multi-threading, with one thread for the server part and one thread for the client part, but an issue is keeping them from hanging. Since both programs are identical there way be a way to listen and simultaneously attempt to connect to the other host.

3) I am also having trouble with making my server listen for connections to it, and do not know how to automatically have it pull the ip address from my computer.

Thanks for any help.

EDIT: This is on a LAN only.

Comment: Have you read this at least? http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial239_Csharp-Chat-Part-1---Building-the-Chat-Client.html

Answer (score 1):

Everything you need to know is in Microsoft's docs.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w89fhyex.aspx